# Renaming a WCF service hosted on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I have renamed a WCF service and everything works just fine on my test/development environment. However, the service is not accessible on my production environment, which is IIS. When trying to access the service the client receives roughly the following error:

> The request failed with the error: The type Old_Service_Name.Some_Type could not be found.

In other words, IIS should be informed about the renaming of the service. How do I tell IIS, preferably using IIS Manager, that the service has a new name?

Comment: did you update your service config? Can you access the service from your browser?

Comment: @evgenyl: I have updated the service config. I cannot access the iis service from the browser (though I can access yhe development service, which isn't hosted on iis, from the browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the service.svc file,  change the `Service` attribute of the `ServiceHost` tag so that it suits your new service name. Namely, replace `Old_Service_Name.Some_Type` with `New_Service_Name.Some_Type`.